# Remove method for linkedList implementation in Java

Tags: java, pointers, methods, linked-list

I have this method from lecture on removing elements from `linkedList` at `specified index`.
I understand how the method works, but I do not understand why the `for-loop` leaves the `current node pointer` two index before the desired index.

Here is the method:

```
public void remove(int index) {
        if (index == 0) {
            // removing the first element must be handled specially
            front = front.next;
        } else {
            // removing some element further down in the list;
            // traverse to the node before the one we want to remove
            ListNode current = front;
            for (int i = 0; i < index - 1; i++) {
                current = current.next;
            }

            // change its next pointer to skip past the offending node
            current.next = current.next.next;
        }
    }
```

The `for-loop` goes from `0 to < index-1`, while I thought it should go from `0 to < index`. In this way, the pointer is at one `index` before the `index` that needed to be deleted. However, the above method works fine.

For eg: 
in the below `LinkedList` [image]

Lets consider removing `Node C`. By the above loop-construct, `current pointer` will be pointing at `Node A` and `current.next` will be `Node B`. `current.next.next` will be `Node C`. Doing `current.next=current.next.next` will result in `Node B` deletion rather than `Node C`.

I think something is wrong with my understanding, can somebody explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The for-loop goes from 0 to < index-1

In your example, removing `C` means index is `2`. So `i` only goes to `0`, since `1` is not `< 1`.

`current` starts at `A`, the `for` loops once and `current` goes to `B`.

`current` is `B`, so `current.next.next` is `D`, which effectively removes `C`.